# New php syntax (for me)

Tags: php, yii2

I have some experience with php, but I just saw a syntax (Yii2 reference) I'm not sure how to read and couldn't find explicitly in the docs.  What does the "[new" mean?  Does this define an array of new objects?

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Credit();
    $modelReferences = [new CreditRefence()];
    $modelFiles = [new CreditFile()];
```

Comment: It's the same as: `$obj = new xy(); $array = [$obj];`

Comment: `Does this define an array of new objects?` - yes

Answer (score 1):

> As of PHP 5.4 you can also use the short array syntax, which replaces array() with [].

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

The new  is for create a new object/model  in this case you are creating 3 object  Credit, CreditRefence, CreditFile

the first is assingne $model a simple var

the other are assigned to array  .. [] is the new shortcut sintax for array in php 5.4

In your application  probably you have  Credit, CreditRefence, CreditFile  in model